# Part of PropTypes Shape

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have something that looks like this:

```
export const LocalesModel = PropTypes.shape({
  defaultLocale: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  supportedLanguages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  messages: MessageModel,
});
```

In a component I am getting that model like this:

```
import { LocalesModel } from '...';

const Component = () => ...

Component.propTypes = {
   supportedLanguages: ???
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
Component.propTypes = {
   supportedLanguages: LocalesModel.supportedLanguages
}
```

but I know this doesn't work. Is there any way to get a property of a PropTypes shape - or do I just have to extract `supportedLanguages` out of `LocalesModel`?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the shape without `PropTypes.shape`:

```
export const LocalesModel = {
  defaultLocale: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  supportedLanguages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  messages: MessageModel,
};
```

And then add `PropTypes.shape` where you use it:

```
Component.propTypes = {
 supportedLanguages: PropTypes.shape(LocalesModel.supportedLanguages)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of exporting without shape, I was just wondering if there was another way. Trying (and failing) to avoid rewriting a bunch of code :( Thanks for the answer!